# Same object in different classes?

Tags: c#, winforms, object

I've been coding a Minecraft launcher using Windows Forms. I made it download the launcher if it doesn't detect one. The variable for the EXE is called `_exe` (I used a get-set for it). I made another form download the launcher async (for a progress bar, talk about aesthetics!). In `Program.cs`, where all the big stuff happens (where `Main()` is), I have a method called `Boot()` which loads all the settings and checks for missing files (Minecraft.exe, Launch.bat (which sets the environment variable `%APPDATA%` because I have no idea how to set environment variables and launch Minecraft with that). When the DownloadLauncher form initializes, it tells me that it's downloading to the folder the launcher is in (which is the default option) although in the settings it's already set to use the original `%APPDATA%` folder. I know this is a case of objects being declared numerous times but I have no idea how to fix it because it's on such a large scale.
[Program.cs](http://pastebin.ca/2531296) , [DownloadLauncher.cs](http://pastebin.ca/2531297)
Problem is that the variable `prog._rw.var._exe` in line 23 isn't supposed to be `.minecraft\Minecraft.exe` but `(%APPDATA%)\.minecraft\Minecraft.exe`

Comment: By the way, this is my first time ever using WinForms :)

Comment: Even though I wouldn't approve of it, you could always go ahead and store that variable as a public property in a static class. It can then be 'shared'. 
May I ask why you are programming a minecraft launcher if there is a perfectly fine one out there already?

Comment: I'm planning on having it install mods and such. Can you provide an example of a public property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static class VariableStore
{
    public static string MinecraftPath
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Now to 'set' your variable, you'd call:

```
VariableStore.MinecraftPath = "%appdata%\\roaming\\.minecraft";
```

You access it the same way:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(VariableStore.MinecraftPath);
```

Keep in mind that this is a very crude solution. Also, if you're planning to go through with your project (which sounds like a really nice learning project), I'd advice you to read up a little bit more about WinForms and how they work before you go any further, as you have multiple design flaws already. Don't give up and good luck! :)

Comment: What kind of design flaws? o-o

Comment: For example your naming scheme for public and private variables. If underscopes are used, they're almost ALWAYS used for private and not for public variables. Also, try to start and use properties instead of public variables. Not only do they add a lot more flexibility, but it's also a good design choice.

Comment: Oh, and by the way, you can easily retrieve the appdata directory of the user by calling `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)` :)

Comment: Do I put that code in a separate class? Can I access it from _anywhere_ with `VariableStore.MCPath`?

Comment: A static class is a class which will not be instanced. So you won't need to go ahead and stay `variableStore myVarStore = new VariableStore()` etc... Instead, the static means it's just plain there, you can call it from (almost) anywhere. This approach has its downsides, but I suppose it'll serve just fine for your cause :) so to answer your question, you'll have to put the code for the static class into its own class file, sure.